# Efficient Way to Find Pair Orderings?

Tags: algorithm, math, sorting, statistics, theory

Let's say I have three arrays `a`, `b`, and `c` of equal length `N`.  The elements of each of these arrays come from a [totally ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ordering), but are not sorted.  I also have two index variables, `i` and `j`.  For all `i != j`, I want to count the number of index pairs such that `a[i] < a[j]`, `b[i] > b[j]` and `c[i] < c[j]`.  Is there any way this can be done in less than O(N ^ 2) time complexity, for example by creative use of sorting algorithms?

Notes:  The inspiration for this question is that, if you only have two arrays, `a` and `b`, you can find the number of index pairs such that `a[i] < a[j]` and `b[i] > b[j]` [in O(N log N) with a merge sort](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2282833).  I'm basically looking for a generalization to three arrays.

For simplicity, you may assume that no two elements of any array are equal (no ties).

Comment: Are you wanting a single array when this algorithm finishes?  E.g. an array which stores all elements from `a`, `b` and `c` in a sorted order?

Comment: Could you give an example of what a "well-defined total ordering" is?

Comment: A total ordering on a set holds antisymmetry, transitivity, and totality; see the Wiki article for more info. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

Comment: @David:  All I want when the algorithm finishes is a single integer, representing **how many** i, j pairs with this property exist.

Comment: If each array has a total ordering, then for all i <= j, a[i] <= a[j], b[i] <= b[j], c[i] <= c[j].  Is this correct? In this case, isn't the answer then |a| + |c| (since the number of times b[i] > b[j] is 0)?

Comment: @David: the elements in the arrays are members of a totally ordered set, i.e. they *can* be sorted, but are not.

Comment: @larsmans: the question says that the elements of *each array* have a total ordering.  If what you say is the case, then I'd recommend that the question be reworded to: "the elements of each array come from a set which has a total ordering (but the arrays themselves are not sorted.)"  I also deleted my answer in light of this and am waiting for the asker to reword the question.

Comment: @David, sorry, I should have said "for each array, the elements are members of some totally ordered set". However, @dsimcha's wording is the more usual way of expressing this.

Comment: Is there any reason you have chosen `>` for one array, but `<` for the others?  It seems like this is an arbitrary choice, since you can just choose to reverse the ordering.

Comment: @comingstorm:  No, no reason.  It is an arbitrary choice.  In fact, the fact that I chose `>` was to suggest that it's completely arbitrary.

Comment: your question is better suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Daniel No, that site is for research-level questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By sorting the array a and rearranging the arrays b and c at the same time, we can suppose that a[i] < a[j] <=> i < j. So we need to find the number of pairs (i,j) such that i < j, b[i] > b[j] and c[i] < c[j]. Let's view (b[i], c[i]) as a point on a plane. We add the points one by one. Each time we add a point (b[j], c[j]), first we count the number of already added points (i < j) such that b[i] > b[j] and c[i] < c[j]. Then we add the point j and proceed to the next one. The sum of the numbers obtained at each step is our result.

Now it seems that this kind of queries can be fulfilled by two-dimensional segment tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree The cost of one iteration will be O(log^2 n), and the total complexity is O(n log^2 n).

(Note that I assume here that the elements of arrays are numbers. It's OK, because using a sorting we can always replace the elements of an array with numbers from 1 to n so that the order was preserved.)

Edit: In fact, a simpler structure called Fenwick tree or binary indexed tree is sufficient. See this link: http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees#2d